# Is there a way to cycle through indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing, cycle

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

If I have `list1` as shown above, the index of the last value is `3`, but is there a way that if I say `list1[4]`, it would become `list1[0]`?

Comment: Try `list[-1]`.

Comment: Nevermind, I can't read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can you modulo math like:

#### Code:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print(list1[4 % len(list1)])
```

#### Results:

```
1
```

Answer (score 3):

In the situation you described, I myself use the method @StephenRauch suggested. But given that you added `cycle` as a tag, you might want to know there exists such a thing as [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle).

It returns an iterator for you to loop forever over an iterable in a cyclic manner. I don't know your original problem, but you might find it useful.

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.cycle([1, 2, 3]):
   # Do something
   # 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

Be careful with the exit conditions though, you might find yourself in an endless loop.

Answer (score 3):

You could implement your own class that does this.

```
class CyclicList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        index = index % len(self) if isinstance(index, int) else index
        return super().__getitem__(index)

cyclic_list = CyclicList([1, 2, 3, 4])

cyclic_list[4] # 1
```

In particular this will preserve all other behaviours of `list` such as slicing.